# Transmit and receive in PDO for CANopen - Why use transmit channel?

Tags: can, canopen

According to CiA 301, there is something called `TPDO Mapping` and `TPDO Communication`.

[image]

TPDO communication is used for describing how the message is going to be sent for example in every 100ms or for every 10th `sync` message.

TPDO mapping is used to describe what data the software is going to pick from the `object dictionary` to create the message that are going to be sent out.

`PDO` is a `producer & consumer`

[image]

So my question is: If PDO is a producer and consumer, why use TPDO channel when you are going to send?

Because when you send a PDO message, you are sending to the receive channel.

[image]

Normally, a producer sends to the consumer. That means TX -> RX. In that case, I only need to send to eg `0x200 + Node ID` if I want to send to PDO RX channel 1 or `0x280 + Node ID` if I want to send to PDO RX channel 2.

But when should RX send to TX? Will that happen too in CANopen? Because PDO is a transmit to receive service, not transmit to receive and receive to transmit. Right?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why is it a problem that CANopen keeps TPDO and RPDO separate? Suppose I want to send something every 10ms but I want to receive something else at any time it appears on the bus. Using the same PDO for that would be cumbersome.

Comment: As for the COBID they are just _default values_ so that you know what each node expects before you start customizing things. Imagine for example a control system with one ECU and _n_ "dumb" CANopen I/O modules. It would be easiest to give the I/O modules node id 1 to n and configure COBID accordingly in the ECU only, so that you can easily replace them. Would you instead do the other way around and configure each I/O module to suit the default COBID in the ECU, you will have to do that in each and every I/O module, which isn't practical.

Comment: @Lundin I got confused because all data sheets that I have don't show any RX -> TX. So I assume that ALL PDO's acts the same, even if they are labeled as TX and RX? Right?

Comment: @Lundin TPDO sends to RPDO right? Ok. But does RPDO sends to TPDO?

Comment: @Lundin For example: If I want to produce a PDO1 message to node 2, then I use RPDO COB ID = `0x200 + Node ID = 0x202`. If the consumer want to reply with a PDO1 message, it will send out TPDO COB ID = `0x180 + Node ID = 0x182` because Node ID = 2. Is that correct? If yes: What type of request can be sended with PDO? I thought that PDO was only producer and consumer, and not server and client or master and slave.